# If my iOS app pairs with a device using Core Bluetooth, will other apps have access to the device?

Tags: ios, swift, core-bluetooth

From Android documentation:

> Caution: When a user pairs their device with another device using BLE, the data that's communicated between the two devices is accessible to all apps on the user's device.
>
> For this reason, if your app captures sensitive data, you should implement app-layer security to protect the privacy of that data.

Is this also true for iOS? I haven't found anything on it and I assumed because iOS doesn't show the true MAC addresses of devices this wouldn't be an issue, but just wanted to check. Thanks

Comment: regardless of whether you pair or simply connect to a BLE device, other apps can't intercept the data that your app exchanges with that device. However, other apps can make their own connection and communicate with that device as long as it visible; pairing doesn't really change that

Answer (score 1):

Yes, iOS also works in a similar way.  And if you want private communication, you also need to maintain app layer security. Thus android wear, galaxy watch, and other similar devices use encrypted communication in the app layer.

If you already know the details. BLE communication works via Gatt Characteristics.

Consider there are two health applications running on an iOS device and the user also using an activity tracker device. In that case if the user wants to connect both of the health apps with that tracker, he certainly can do it. Both apps will be able to communicate with the activity tracker and get sensor data using the **CBCentral** module. Look at the diagram for Details.

On the other hand, In general, vice versa will not possible. Because if both iOS apps use **Peripheral Role** they will register two different instances of BLE-Service even if using the same UUID. Thus it will force two apps to communicate with completely different characteristics instances. However, it is also possible to work with two peripheral apps with the same UUID but this is not what the BLE developers ever wanted.

[image: BLE Communication with Multiple iOS App]

Answer (score 0):

you need to provide app level security based on Service UUID, so that devices having the app with only same service UUID can connect.